# MySQL, get the last created table name

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to get the last created table name in a given database ?

Comment: You have probably a design fault, if you need that information. All database data intentionally made abstract.

Comment: Yes, You're right, but it's not my database, and I must use it

Comment: @YourCommonSense, This is about forensics. Nothing to do with db design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'some_database' order by create_time desc limit 1;
```